# removing items from listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

In Windows Forms Application I have a listbox with duplicated items (for example there are items: 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4). I am removing every other item using this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ItemsCount/2; i++)
{
     listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.Items[ItemsCount - 2 * i - 1]);
}
```

It removes items with index number 7,5,3 and 1. The result is listbox with items: 1,2,3,4.
Until now everything works.

However, when the listbox has items: 1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2, the result should be listbox: 1,2,1,2.
The problem is, that the result is 1,1,2,2.
Do you have any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through the code in the debugger to see what's happening.

Comment: Why not using % 2 if you can to remove the list size by 50% ?

Comment: Please specify your environment: WPF, WinForms, Xamarin, UWP, ASP.NET, Unity ...

Answer (score 2):

Probably what's confusing you is that the [`Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.remove?view=netcore-3.1) method takes in the ***value*** of an item to remove, and then *it removes the first occurrence of it*.

Instead, if you want to remove the item at a ***specific index***, then you should use the [`RemoveAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat?view=netcore-3.1) method instead, which takes the *index* of the item to remove:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ItemsCount/2; i++)
{
     listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ItemsCount - 2 * i - 1);
}
```

---

And because you asked why it was happening, in your first example, you get the duplicates removed because the only instances of any number are all next to each other, so it appears that every other item is being removed.

In the second example, however, that's not the case. Here's what happens:

```
ItemsCount = 8
Starting values: {1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2}
i = 0
Remove [ItemsCount - 2 * i - 1] = [8 - 2 * 0 - 1] = [7]
The item at index 7 is '2', so we remove the first '2'

New values: {1,1,2,1,1,2,2}
i = 1
Remove [ItemsCount - 2 * i - 1] = [8 - 2 * 1 - 1] = [5]
The item at index 5 is '2', so we remove the first '2'

New values: {1,1,1,1,2,2}
i = 2
Remove [ItemsCount - 2 * i - 1] = [8 - 2 * 2 - 1] = [3]
The item at index 3 is '1', so we remove the first '1'

New values: {1,1,1,2,2}
i = 3
Remove [ItemsCount - 2 * i - 1] = [8 - 2 * 2 - 1] = [1]
The item at index 1 is '1', so we remove the first '1'

Ending values: {1,1,2,2}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Great answer @Rufus L

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [modulus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.op_modulus?view=netcore-3.1) operator to select all odd or even indexed elements in an array, like this.

```
public static void Main()
{
    //var items = new List<int>(){1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4};
    var items = new List<int>(){1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2};
    
    // select all elements at the odd index of an array. To get the even indexed item, use 'index % 2 == 0'
    var updatedItems = items.Where((item, index) => index % 2 != 0);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', updatedItems));
}
```

Use this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eMkDM0) to experiment.

Or more tailored to your scenario:

```
listBox1.Items = listBox1.Items.Where((item, index) => index % 2 != 0);
```

Comment: You do not check if the items are really duplicated.... is just a selection based on odd and even

Comment: OP didn't notice anything about deduplication. He just stated 'I am removing every other item using this code'., which is exactly what the code above does. Also, he mentioned the expected result should be 1,2,1,2 (with duplicates).

Comment: @DA The expected result is `{1,2,1,2}`, which is exactly every other item as the first part of this answer addresses.